# Why is my drop down list not showing up

Tags: php, html, css, html-select

```
       $count  = 4;

       echo '<select class="form-control multiplechose_questionTypes" name="quiz_category" id="category">
             <option class="multiplechose_questionTypes" value=""disabled selected>Select the answer</option>';

                  for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

                    echo '<option class="multiplechoiceguessess" value="test"</option>';
                  }
        echo'</select>';
```

css

```
.multiplechose_questionTypes {  
border-style: solid  ! important;
border-color: #337ab7 ! important;
color: #140D40 ! important;
}

.multiplechoiceguessess {
background-color: #fff ! important;
color: #140D40 ! important;
}
```

variable $count has the value 4.

So it should print test 4 times, and it does print 4 times when I inspect the elements but I tried changing the colours using css and no help, is this caused by some other problem ?

Comment: put proper close tag <option></option>

Comment: Typos are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some typo mistakes.

```
$count  = 4;

   echo '<select class="form-control multiplechose_questionTypes" name="quiz_category" id="category">
         <option class="multiplechoiceguessess" value="" disabled selected>Select the answer</option>';

              for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

                echo '<option class="multiplechoiceguessess" value="test">test</option>'; //added ">" and display text
              }
    echo'</select>';
```

Comment: yeah this solution fixed it, thanks, can't identify what you changed, mind telling me what that typo was ? lol

Comment: I commented in near the option tag what you missed

Comment: but I want to pass in the value like this value="test", not like the way you changed it to

Comment: just so I can display stuffs from database

Comment: ya you can display your database values by replacing "test" in the option tag.

Comment: This is off-topic and you are not supposed to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a mistake in your options, try to replace by that :

```
echo '<option class="multiplechoiceguessess" value="test">Test</option>';
```

Comment: This is off-topic and you are not supposed to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You missed **>** on the **option** tag.

Comment: This is off-topic and you are not supposed to answer.